# "Hacking" a way to a remote shell in 5 characters

Tags: bash, security, shell

This weekend, there was a CTF wargame happening, Secuinside CTF 2013 ( http://war.secuinside.com/ )

Being a computer security enthousiast, I took a look at the challenges, and at their solutions after the CTF was over.

One of the challenges was about **getting a remote shell on a server**, given that a daemon called "givemeshell" is running on this server. What the daemon does is keeping a socket open on a chosen port, let's say port 12345.

When the socket receives something, the daemon takes the **first 5 chars** and launch them in a shell.

For example, if I send `cat file`, the daemon will launch the command `cat f` in a shell. **No response is sent**, so I can't know the result of the command.

**The objective is to read a file** containing the flag.

Now, someone gave me this solution :

```
$ nc 1.2.3.4 12345
4<>a

$ nc 1.2.3.4 12345
sh<&4
sh>&4
cat flag
The flag is _FLAG_
```

I tested this solution and it works. But after spending several hours trying to understand it, I still can't figure out what it does and why it works. I understand this is about redirecting something...

Can someone explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: Try http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, I considered posting there but I think this question is more about shell programming than security.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

4 is your connection's file descriptor.

0 is the program stdin, 1 is the program stdout, 2 is the program stderr, when you created a socket to listen for connections it was then assigned to 3, and when it accepted your connection, a new file descriptor of number 4 was created to handle this connection.

4 is the ID of the file descriptor of your connection to the backdoor, assuming you are the first one to connect.

You then type `sh<&4`. It opens `sh` and tell it should get all input directly from your connection.

Right now you are already in full control of the shell, because `sh` took over and every command you send is interpreted directly by it. But you still cannot see any output!

Then you type `sh>&4` to open a new level of `sh` inside the other saying it should push all output to your file descriptor. The trick is done! Two-way communication.

Comment: Assuming they were available, wouldn't running `vim`, `nano`, or`emacs` (or others), and then using the programs built-in file open capability opening `flag` do the same thing, but in a much more straight-forward manner?

Comment: Not if you are limited to 5 characters and unable to see any output.

Comment: Is `4<>a` part of the solution, or is it just a hint?

Comment: Apparently `4<>a` is not useful, you can get a shell without send that command. I don't know why it was part of the solution given to me. It wasn't a hint during the CTF.

Comment: @arnaud576875 `4<>a` may be needed to create the file descriptor before you can read from it with `<&4`, otherwise you may get a “Bad file descriptor” error message. `4<>a` basically creates the file descriptor 4 which reads from and writes to the file `a`.